# Dataset Value of each iteration repeating twice in Anylogic Parameter Variation Experiment

Tags: anylogic

I have this model, that I am working on where I need to run Parameter Variation experiment. I have the following dataset on the parameter experiment page, which I am updating after each simulation run (see the java action)

[image]

But when I run the experiment, it seems the data of each iteration is repeating twice.

[image]

In the above image, you will see iteration 0, has two results. One has a value greater than 0, and the other one is 0.

This is happening for all my datasets. What is wrong here?

Comment: impossible to know... run the simulation using the same seed and the same parameters to see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably set the dataset properties wrong. Ensure they do not also update themselves, i.e. they only receive data when you call your code.

Comment: That must be it. Thanks.